# How to display number of times a word repeated after a common pattern

Tags: linux, uniq

I have a file which has N number of line 
For example

```
This/is/workshop/1
This/is/workshop/2
This/is/workshop/3
This/is/workshop/4
This/is/workshop/5
```

How to get the below result using uniq command:

```
This/is/workshop/ =5
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the common pattern and what is the repeated word? Do you only search for this particular string (`This/is/workshop/`), or do you have a range of strings?

Comment: I meant "This/is/workshop/" is common to every line.Also  i have range  of strings

Comment: Is there a pattern for your “pattern” (the prefix string)?

Comment: Yes In this example "This/is/workshop/" is my pattern .This include "/" also

Comment: So, which repeated word are you trying to count? The numbers that come after your pattern are not repeated. Also, which range of strings? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Sorry I post my question in wrong way .Now i will explain with Clear picture

I have a file which has following lines
This/is/workshop/1
This/is/workshop/2
This/is/workshop/3
This/is/workshop/4

if we use uniq -c file_name i will get
1 This/is/workshop/1
1 This/is/workshop/2
..
But i need following result
5 This/is/workshop

Is this possible using uniq. If not which command should i use in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there are a couple tools you can utilize here. Familiarize yourself with grep, cut, and uniq. My process for doing something like this may not be ideal, but given your original question I'll try to tailor the process to the lines in the file you've given.

First you'll want to grep the file for the relevant strings. Then you can pass it through to cut, declaring the fields you want to *include* by specifying the delimiter and also the number of fields. Lastly, you can pipe this through to uniq to count it.

Example:

### Contents of file.txt

`This/is/workshop/1
This/is/workshop/2
This/is/workshop/3
This/is/workshop/4
This/is/workshop/5`

## Use grep, cut and uniq

`$ grep "This/is/workshop/" file.txt | cut -d/ -f1-3 | uniq -c
   5 This/is/workshop`

To specify the delimiter in cut, you use the -d flag and the delimiter you want to use. Each field is what exists between delimiters, starting at 1. For this, we want the first three. Then just pipe it through to uniq to get the count you are after.